Is it possible to insert an exact live template using keymap shortcut in WebStorm?
I am currently using WebStorm for dev, so I want to know is it possible to insert an exact live template using keymap shortcut in WebStorm ?
For example:

Select a variable;
Then press Ctrl + L, it will inset a template code to next line.

Like this one in VS Code:
VS Code gif example
I know some usage like .log, but seems it will break the original code and it not what I expecting.
And I also found a plugin called logit accroding to this post, but it seems just can insert one pattern, not so 'customize'.
AFAIK I can implement this in VSCode like this below:
// keybindings.json
{
    "key": "ctrl+l",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
                "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
                "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "console.log('${1:$CLIPBOARD} :>>', ${1:$CLIPBOARD});"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}


The idea behind Live Templates is that you type some small ID (abbreviation), press the expand key (normally it's Tab) and it will replace that abbreviation with the code snippet. Therefore you cannot assign a custom shortcut to specific live template. The best idea I have right now -- try combining it with Macros

P.S. Actual ticket for assigning keyboard shortcut to a particular live template: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-337 . You can go through the comments there and related ones and see what options are available.
